# VLOOK up columns value formula

Tags: excel-formula

I have this table:

```
Col1 Col2   Col3    Col4    Col5    Col6
123  234    456     678      ABC    JKL
            562     376      DEF    
            852     951      GHI    
            123     234      JKL
```

What I want to know is, how to get the value of Col5 if Col1 and Col2 is equal to Col3 and Col4?

I want to insert the value of Col5 to Col6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an array formula to retrieve the row intersection of some `MATCH`. Then use that `MATCH` as an `INDEX`:

[image]

Note that the formula

```
=INDEX(E:E,MATCH(A2&B2,C:C&D:D,0))
```

has to be entered as an array formula (using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>).

Answer (score 0):

```
=IF (Logic_Test, Value_if_True, Value_if_False)

=if(a1&b1=c1&d1,e1,"")
```